# ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 Live binding - Issue with Sys.registerComponent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, asp.net-ajax, live

I am trying to design a client template using the AJAX 4.0 framework with live binding.

I have WCF Service defined called VesselData (will provide code if needed) which returns a datatable class called VesselCollection. Also, I am referencing the following scripts in master file: MicrosoftAjax.debug.js, MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.debug.js, MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.debug.js.

The problem is the templates donot fill up with data, and fetchData method on dataContext goes to failCallback method without any way to know what went wrong. Moreover, I get several javascript errors like "Object doesnt support this property or method" on "Sys.registercomponent" inside one of the .js files.

Please, need some help here..

**Code**:

```
< %@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Vessels.aspx.cs" CodeFile="~/Vessels.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleAJAXDatabinding.Vessels" %>

< %@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

< asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">


< script type="text/javascript">

    var dataContext = new Sys.Data.DataContext();
    dataContext.set_serviceUri("../Services/VesselData.svc");
    dataContext.initialize();

    function bind() {
        dataContext.fetchData("GetVesselData", { $top: 1 }, Sys.Data.MergeOption.overwriteChanges, "GET", function () { document.getElementById("template").style.display = "block"; alert('fetch succeeded.'); }, function (error) { alert('fetch failed \n' + error.valueOf().toString()); }, 2000);
    }


 < /script>

<style type="text/css">
.sys-template { display:block; visibility:visible; }
</style>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" ScriptMode = "Release" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/VesselData.svc" />
    </Services>
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>



< div id = "view">
    < ul id="template" 
        class="sys-template" sys:attach="dataview"
        dataview:autofetch="true"
        dataview:dataprovider="dataContext"
        dataview:fetchoperation="GetVesselData">
        < li>
               < h3>{{ VesselName }}</h3>
              < div>
                {{ VesselID }} <br />
                {{ CompanyID }} <br />
                {{ PublishQuestionnaire88 }} <br />
              < /div>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div >
<input type="button"
       value="Perform binding"
       onclick="bind()" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but I was using the Ajax script files from the CDN until I realize that Sys.registerComponent is defined on MicrosoftAjax.debug.js that comes on the sdk on the odata.org [here](http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk#/media/15213/odatajavascriptlibrary.zip). Not weird enough if you use the minified version MicrosoftAjax.js it breaks on `if (serviceUri) {
        this.set_path(serviceUri);
    }` saying that set_path is not defined.

In the end I had to use the debug version of MicrosoftAjax, MicrosoftAjaxDataContext, MicrosoftAjaxOpenData and MicrosoftAjaxTemplates and manualy compress the files for release.

I hope someone find out of this mistake and fix the respective files and upload the new version to the cdn.